# Render blocking css only bootstrap 76/100

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, pagespeed

i have a server with nginx + spdy + module_pagespeed installed and i'm making page speed test from google.

This is my current template for the test which obtain 76/100, a basic template with only bootstrap:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<title>Welcome!</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
<body>
 <div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top navbar-inverse" role="navigation">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Project name</a>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div><!-- /.nav-collapse -->
  </div><!-- /.container -->
</div><!-- /.navbar -->

<div class="container">

  <div class="row row-offcanvas row-offcanvas-right">

    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-9">
      <p class="pull-right visible-xs">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" data-toggle="offcanvas">Toggle nav</button>
      </p>
      <div class="jumbotron">
        <h1>Hello, world!</h1>
        <p>This is an example to show the potential of an offcanvas layout pattern in Bootstrap. Try some responsive-range viewport sizes to see it in action.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-6 col-sm-6 col-lg-4">
          <h2>Heading</h2>
          <p>Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Donec sed odio dui. </p>
          <p><a class="btn btn-default" href="#" role="button">View details &raquo;</a></p>
        </div><!--/span-->
        <div class="col-6 col-sm-6 col-lg-4">
          <h2>Heading</h2>
          <p>Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Donec sed odio dui. </p>
          <p><a class="btn btn-default" href="#" role="button">View details &raquo;</a></p>
        </div><!--/span-->
        <div class="col-6 col-sm-6 col-lg-4">
          <h2>Heading</h2>
          <p>Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Donec sed odio dui. </p>
          <p><a class="btn btn-default" href="#" role="button">View details &raquo;</a></p>
        </div><!--/span-->
        <div class="col-6 col-sm-6 col-lg-4">
          <h2>Heading</h2>
          <p>Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Donec sed odio dui. </p>
          <p><a class="btn btn-default" href="#" role="button">View details &raquo;</a></p>
        </div><!--/span-->
        <div class="col-6 col-sm-6 col-lg-4">
          <h2>Heading</h2>
          <p>Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Donec sed odio dui. </p>
          <p><a class="btn btn-default" href="#" role="button">View details &raquo;</a></p>
        </div><!--/span-->
        <div class="col-6 col-sm-6 col-lg-4">
          <h2>Heading</h2>
          <p>Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Donec sed odio dui. </p>
          <p><a class="btn btn-default" href="#" role="button">View details &raquo;</a></p>
        </div><!--/span-->
      </div><!--/row-->
    </div><!--/span-->

    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3 sidebar-offcanvas" id="sidebar" role="navigation">
      <div class="list-group">
        <a href="#" class="list-group-item active">Link</a>
        <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Link</a>
        <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Link</a>
        <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Link</a>
        <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Link</a>
        <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Link</a>
        <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Link</a>
        <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Link</a>
        <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Link</a>
        <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Link</a>
      </div>
    </div><!--/span-->
  </div><!--/row-->

  <hr>

  <footer>
    <p>&copy; Company 2014</p>
  </footer>

</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

I obtain 76/100 and an alert that say render blocking,

[page speed test](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wek5V.png)

When i remove the bootstrap.min.css i get 100/100, ¿is there any way to fix this issue?

Regards,

Answer (score 1):

You only seem to have an issue in the mobile test and not the desktop version. Google has different guidelines for the different cases since usually the mobile connection is slower, less content is shown (which means not as much CSS is needed) and so on.

Some things I’d look into:

- Is your version of Bootstrap the *complete* Bootstrap? Try to only include the parts that you actually need. In 90% of the cases there is something you can remove.
- Does your mobile site need exactly the same CSS as the desktop version? Try to identify elements that you maybe don’t even use on smaller screens and ship a seperate file that you use only on small screens (and don’t use the big one)

If you use the mod_pagespeed module (either on Apache or NGINX) there is a setting to dynamically inline certain parts of the CSS into the `<head>` which is what Google recommends you do for big stylesheets. I haven’t used this setting yet though so I can’t provide any help there.

Hope that helps.